# in Flex 3.2 Having troubles converting remote object result to specific object on client side in modules

Tags: apache-flex, remoteobject

in Flex 3.2 Having troubles converting remote object result to specific object on client side in modules.

For example I have VIPSAdmin module.

it has function

```
private function doResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
var data_:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result); 
var result:ResultDTO = data_[0] as ResultDTO;
if(!result.isError()) {
    trace(result.result);
    vipsAdminDTO = result.result as VIPSAdmin;
    compId= vipsAdminDTO.compId; // second time dying here
}
```

}

Function invoked when I get data from remote objet.

First time all great,when I unload this modeule and load it again:

data_[0] as ResultDTO;

Performs fine, but

vipsAdminDTO = result.result as VIPSAdmin;

vipsAdminDTO  always null!

Even when

trace(result.result);

produces [object VIPSAdmin]

What a heck I missing here!? Looks like it just cannot do

result.result as VIPSAdmin;

even when trace and debug says it is instance of VIPSAdmin

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with your cast.  sometimes the results are set to null if the cast fails.  You can try: VIPSAdmin(result.result) instead of result.result as VIPSAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what is the problem, problem is that when I first instantiate something in module then in main app, somehow classes are not alined even that they are identical !

So solution is to make a fake instance in application class first, then if you use that same class to make an instance in module it will work!

I do it very simple in my main application class I just added:

```
VIPSAdmin;
```

This seems to create some sort of ghost instance, which I belie will be pickup by GC later, but will build tables of instances properly! Which solved my problem.

Not sure if this is appropriate solution ! but it sure works.